# Power BI - Split a string input into new rows in a table

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I'm working with Dynamics CRM project operations. I am currently putting together a report based on task effort that is being assigned to resources.

The data being pulled contains a 'planned work' column. These are strings with multiple dates and hours included in the payload.

A single cell example is:

```
[{""End"":""\/Date(1660838400000)\/"",""Hours"":8,""Start"":""\/Date(1660809600000)\/""},{""End"":""\/Date(1660924800000)\/"",""Hours"":9,""Start"":""\/Date(1660892400000)\/""},{""End"":""\/Date(1661184000000)\/"",""Hours"":9,""Start"":""\/Date(1661151600000)\/""}]
```

What I need to do is, pull the dates and hours for each entry and add it to a new table so they each have their own rows. Example desired output for this cell:

| Start Date | End Date | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1660809600000 | 1660838400000 | 8 |
| 1660892400000 | 1660924800000 | 9 |
| 1661151600000 | 1660924800000 | 9 |

The cells can vary in length with multiple entries so it needs to take that into account.

Is there anyone how can point me in the right direction on how this can be done in Power BI?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wiq6OUYpRcs1LAVFWIELfJbEkVcPQzMzAwtjCxAAENPVBEjogwiO/tKgYrNYCzA8uSSwqwabXwNIMSW+tDh57LI1MLHDbY4nfHqBmIu0xNIR6hwx7DA1NDVH8E6sUGwsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"""""","""",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
    #"Parsed JSON" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{},Json.Document),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Parsed JSON", "Column1"),
    #"Expanded Column2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1", {"End", "Hours", "Start"}, {"End", "Hours", "Start"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Column2","/Date(","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"End", "Start"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1",")/","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"End", "Start"})
in
    #"Replaced Value2"
```

Comment: Thanks David. This looks promising.
How did you get the text value to pass in for "Binary.FromText"?
What would I need to do to reference the table column I'm working with?

Comment: That is just how text appears when you paste it in PQ. On a column, you'll need to paste everything from the second line onwards and adjust the first line to something like this: #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(<NameOfPreviousStepHere>,"""""","""",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"<ColumnNameHere>"}),

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @David's answer above, you can also do the two replace value transforms in a single step:

```
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Expanded Column2",
        "blah",
        "blah",
        (column_value, new, old) => Text.Select(column_value, {"0".."9"}),
        {"End", "Start"}
    )
```